# DB Connection is getting closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

From the Spring-hibernate-application we are triggering a stored procedure which is taking around 30 mins to execute..when it comes back and spring tries to commit the transaction since we are using spring transaction managment,It fails with the below exception saying the connection is closed.

we are using tomcat server and the connections in the application are managed in Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:588)
      at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
      at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
      at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
      at com.jpmchase.common.service.adjustment.impl.AdjustmentExistingRecServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2ddfbc5.lockUnlockForExport(<generated>)
      at com.jpmchase.adjustment.existingRecord.delegate.AdjustmentExistingRecDelegate.processDataAndExportToExcel(AdjustmentExistingRecDelegate.java:1394)
      ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:187)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
      ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
      ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7c035c41 is closed.
      at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.checkOpen(DelegatingConnection.java:398)
      at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
      at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:211)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112).
```

Please help.

Comment: You should add a bit more context to your question and be more specific in your question. State your assumptions and hypothesis.

Comment: are you sure you didnt close the connection somehow in an earlier process... does this exist in test environment too? is there any difference in your environments? firewall configuration? are thos different machines? do you have any leak, connections doesnt return to the pool? Maybe your FW is configured different in test and prod. Maybe your fw dropps inactive connection, session is invalid when return?

Comment: Seems a timeout issue. Look in the Tomcat log for some errors previous to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your hibernate connection is timing out.
You need to increase the timeout on your hibernate connections.

I don't know which provider you are using, but it shouldn't be too hard to google and figure out how to change the timeout